# How can I view an earlier version of a table on a T-SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, revision-history

I've just done something very silly. In both the productive and development environments on our SSMS server, I've changed the wrong column in one table. I know exactly what rows have been changed, but not what their original values were. I did not use a transaction. Is there any way to view the history of the table or see a backup of it? For example, if I could find what it looked like yesterday, my day would be saved.

Comment: You can only see a backup of the table if you make a backup of the table. Did you make a backup of the table or is there a DBA in your organization that may be taking regular backups? There is no version history automatically captured in sql server unless you or a DBA has set something like that up, which is very unlikely.

Comment: @JNevill I know that we keep log files and that a backup job is regularly ran on the server, but I don't know what those do.

Comment: You'll have to find someone that knows. Not much we can do here across the internet. Someone set up that backup job and it's likely your data can be recovered from that backup. Terribly sorry for the panic you are going through. We've all been there. :(

Comment: Whomever manages the backups ought to be able to restore the database to a different name on the same instance using a full and transaction log backups to the point before your change. That will allow you to update the table using a join to get the original data version.

Comment: Not a solution for data already lost, but this is *exactly* what database snapshots help guard against. I have snapshots created every 2 hours on a rolling basis on both DEV and production secondary AG replica, plus automatic restores of previous full backup - if anything like this happens, recovery is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is to restore the data from a backup (into a separate database or a separate server). If you have transaction log backups, you can also use a point-in-time restore.

You can also try https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-log.aspx, to see if you can find the changes in the transaction log. But it won't work if you are using the SIMPLE recovery model.